# Mongo + Spring Boot Application - E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: mongodb, rest, spring-data

I know questions with similar names exists already, but their solution didn't apply to mine, so wanted to ask it anyway.

Here's my User class. Here as you can see there exists subscribedTo list in which I store users that a user has subscribed to. Anyways, I want to insert a user to the database, however I get "E11000 duplicate key error"

The error is as follows

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-07-22T17:06:20.111+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: newdb.user index: subscribedTo.username dup key: { : null }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: newdb.user index: subscribedTo.username dup key: { : null }",
    "path": "/user/add"
}
```

**The User class**

```
@Document(collection = "user")
@Data
public class User{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=5, max=32)
    private String password;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date dateRegistered;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date dateLastEntry;

    private String profilePictureUrl;

    private List<User> subscribedTo;

    private int active; //0 for false

    public User(@NotBlank String username,
                @NotBlank @Size(min = 5, max = 32) String password,
                @Email String email,
                String profilePictureUrl) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.dateRegistered = new Date();
        this.dateLastEntry = new Date();
        this.profilePictureUrl = profilePictureUrl;
        this.subscribedTo = Arrays.asList();
        this.active = 1;
    }
}
```

So, why such kind of thing is happening? I put unique constraint on username and email, not on the list.

Thanks, beforehand. By the way, I'm really new to MongoDb, so, if anything I've provided isn't enough please tell me so that I'll post them as well.

Comment: share requested data that you want to save and DB unique indices

Answer (score 0):

somehow username variable is setting to null while you are executing this code. Please debug your code and check why null value is going.